# Cannot upload new APK to Google Play because of Google Play services version

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-2.2-froyo, google-play

I have minSdk set to 8 (Froyo) because of client's wish. Google Play won't allow me to upload new .apk. This is what it says:

> Warnings
>   You uploaded an APK that uses Google Play services version 4030500. This will only work with Android API levels of 9 and above. It is discouraged to use this Google Play services version unless you have set the minSdkVersion in your manifest to 9 or higher.

Is there any chance to support versions older than Gingerbread?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would the app *work* on Froyo (with reduced functionality)? If not, increase the SDK version and explain to your client [that there are fewer than 1% of devices which still use Froyo](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use an older version of the Google Play Services to be Froyo compatible.

change in your `build.gradle` file to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.+'
```

ps.: but I strongly advise in explaning to the client that Froyo is dead and gone and users that still have those devices are users that usually only make phone calls and SMS. They never go to Google Play to download new apps because their devices are too old and are not able to run any modern app properly.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to bump SDK verion to 9.

Comment: I have that same line in my `build.gradle` and I'm still getting the same warning (although with Google Play services version different). I'm able to release new apks though. Just the warning saying it wont work with API level 8.

Comment: "Just the warning saying it wont work with API level 8" that means it will crash on Froyo devices. The whole point of my answer is to use that specific version of play services that will not crash on Froyo. Or dump Froyo because it's useless.

Comment: Sorry @PratikButani i stopped using eclipse long time and strong advice people to migrate as soon as possible to AndroidStudio